# How can I tweak this (US) Southern themed cocktail?

Tags: flavor, cocktails

It periodically falls to me to produce thematically-sound cocktails for wife's Book Club meetings.  Tomorrow, we are serving the Southern Discomfort (for 'Gone Girl'):

```
2 oz blood orange juice
1 oz Bourbon (Maker's, this time)
0.5 oz Aperol
0.5 tsp agave syrup (too lazy to make simple)
dash of Scrappy's Aromatic Bitters
```

It's almost there... still, just a little 'meh' - what suggestions to round this off?

Comment: This is essentially a what goes with X question, where X is the recipe so far.  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/should-we-close-questions-structured-like-what-compliments-does-not-work-with?cb=1

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ True, but it also hints at regional tradition. So maybe it's in the grey area? At least it's specific in scope. 
Can we improve it?

Comment: I think it is more chat discussion than a question, @PrestonFitzgerald

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald reducing the scope only reduces the list of equally-fitting ingredients from hundreds to a dozen or two. It is still a list of "what goes with X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some thinly-sliced peaches? Seems relevant to the Southern theme and complementary to both the heavier bourbon flavor and the other fruity notes.

You could sub out the agave for peach syrup if you want to live on the edge.

Rhubarb is also a Southern classic that could be an interesting addition. But I don't know how you'd implement that.

Comment: Scrappy's or someone else makes a rhubarb bitters that's to die for.

Comment: No way. That sounds delicious. Wasn't aware of that product. Thanks for the tip. I found some here from Fee Brothers http://www.feebrothers.com/products/bitters/rhubarb_bitters.php

Comment: Awesome idea.  I can pick up the bitters to try this tonight.  Thanks.